# Issue copying file from Server to Client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, client

I'm new to C and I'm having an issue that I cannot debug for the life of me. I'm trying a very simple task of sending a file from a server to a client.

Server Code:

```
void send_file(int socket, char *filename[100])
{

 char fname[100] = "./upload/";

 strcat(fname,filename);

 printf("%s%", fname);

 FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"rb");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File open error");
    }   

    while(1)
    {
        unsigned char buff[1024]={0};
        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp); //read 256 byte chunk of file
        printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        

        // If read was success, send data. 
        if(nread > 0)
        {
            write(socket, buff, nread);
        }
        if (nread == 0)
        {
    write(socket, buff, nread);

            if (feof(fp))
    {
        printf("Transfer Complete, ID: %d\n",socket);
        break;
    }
            if (ferror(fp))

                printf("Read Error\n");

            break;
        }

    }
fclose(fp);
```

}

So for this code, I take a file name and read the file in 256 byte chunks and then write them which the client then reads.

Client Code:

```
void get_file(int socket, char *fname[100]) {

int bytesReceived = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff));

FILE *fp; 

fp = fopen(fname, "w+"); 

if(NULL == fp)
{
    printf("Error opening file");

}

//Receive data in chunks of 256 bytes 

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);//point to start of file

while(1)
{ 

bytesReceived = read(socket, recvBuff, 1024);

if (bytesReceived > 0) 
{
    fwrite(recvBuff, 1,bytesReceived,fp);
}

if (recvBuff == 0) {    
    break;
}
}

if(bytesReceived < 0)
{
    printf("\n Read Error \n");
}

printf("\nFile OK....Completed\n");
fclose(fp);
```

}

This issue is both sides seem to work however when I read a file on the server side, it reads it fine but it doesn't seem to send all of it. The client receives around 99% of the file each time.

It seems the client side loop never finishes and therefore doesn't write the whole file, the test file Im using is a jpeg and it receives 32768 out of 33010.

Which is 1024 * 32 the remaining 242 bytes aren't written and the loop doesn't seem to end even though the server sends an empty write that should break the loop.

Sending SIGINT to the server does end the client loop and also sends the rest of the file however.

Any insight into what I am doing wrong would be great, thanks!

Edit:

As requested the code that executes the function.

```
void *client_handler(void *socket_desc){

int connfd = *(int *) socket_desc;
char recv_option[128];
char filename[100];
size_t n;
size_t k;

while (1) {

char recv_option[128] = "";

readn(connfd, (unsigned char *) &n, sizeof(size_t));
readn(connfd, (unsigned char *) recv_option, n);

printf("Recieved: %c\n", recv_option[0]);

if (recv_option[0] == 'a') {
    send_servertime(connfd);
    } 

if (recv_option[0] == 'b') {
    send_uname(connfd);
}

if (recv_option[0] == 'c') {
    send_filenames(connfd);
}

if (recv_option[0] == 'd') {

  readn(connfd, (unsigned char *) &k, sizeof(size_t));
  readn(connfd, (unsigned char *) filename, k);

  send_file(connfd, &filename);

    }
}//whileloop

shutdown(connfd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(connfd);

printf("Thread %lu exiting\n", (unsigned long) pthread_self());

shutdown(connfd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(connfd);

return 0;
}  // end client_handler()
```

Comment: `recvBuff == 0` is always false.

Comment: I thought if I send a write with 0 as the recvBuff would solve that?

Comment: FYI:  "read()" on a socket behaves like a "recv()" with no flags set.  "recv()" contains the following in the Ubuntu Linux man page: "When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value  will  be  0  (the traditional "end-of-file" return)." ... Therefore, your client code must treat a zero read on the socket, as a "end-of-file"...

Comment: You correctly test for a failure of "fopen()" in both client and server, however you only write an error message... then continue processing, as if the fopen() succeeded...

Comment: Yeah that's skeleton code until I can fix the code I'm working on currently. It seems if I close the socket it works but it does end my server. I can't get it finish and then keep the server going.

Comment: You only posted the send_file() function of the server... once the server has completed sending the file, that function should return... we can't help you on what the calling function does incorrectly, because you didn't provide it.

Comment: I've posted the function that handles the client via a thread, it simply loops and reads input from the client and executes functions based on that, for the sendfile it also takes a filename specified by the client.

Answer (score 0):

- `recvBuff == 0` can never be true.
- You aren't testing for `bytesReceived == 0`, which is what you should be testing instead of `recvBuff == 0`.

So, you are ignoring end of stream in the client, so your client copy loop never exits, so you never close the output file.

Other problems:

- Don't use `fread()`, `fopen()`, etc. The API is far too problematic. Use `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, `close()`.
- Sending zero bytes at the end of the file is pointless.

Comment: I have implemented the changes you have suggested but it still seems to stick for some reason almost like it never receives the EoS.

Comment: So either you still haven't implemented `if (bytesReceived == 0) { break; }` correctly in the client read loop, or the server hasn't closed the socket.